# Parse String - remove some words from string

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string like:

```
$text = 'Hello this is my string and texts';
```

I've got some *not allowed* words in array:

```
$filtered_words = array(
            'string',
            'text'
        );
```

I want to replace all the filtered words in my `$text` with `***`, so I wrote:

```
$text_array = explode(' ', $text);
        foreach($text_array as $key => $value){
            if(in_array($text_array[$key], $filtered_words)){
                $text = str_replace($text_array[$key], '***', $text);
            }
        }
echo $text;
```

The Output:

```
Hello this is my *** and texts
```

But I need function to also replace `texts` with `***` since it's also contain a filtered word(text).

How I could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace - search for the *array*, it works. The replace string is `***` - just check the manual PHP does this out of the box - see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14919021/367456)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just do it right away, [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) supports to replace from an array into a single string:

```
$text = 'Hello this is my string and texts';

$filtered_words = array(
    'string',
    'texts',
    'text',
);

$zap = '***';

$filtered_text = str_replace($filtered_words, $zap, $text);

echo $filtered_text;
```

Output ([Demo](http://eval.in/10359)):

```
Hello this is my *** and ***
```

Take care you have the largest words first and keep in mind when `str_replace` is in that mode, it will do one replacement after the other - like in your loop. So shorter words - if earlier - could be part of larger words.

If you need something more failsafe you must consider doing a textual analysis first. That could also tell you if you didn't know about words you might want to replace but you didn't thought of so far.

Comment: exclude the word `text` from $filter_words, then the output would be `Hello this is my *** and ***s`, but this should be `Hello this is my *** and ***`

Answer (score 2):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can accept an array as first parameter. So no need of any `for each` loop at all:

```
$filtered_words = array(
    'string',
    'text'
);
$text = str_replace($filtered_words, '***', $text);
```